# Prove the existence of a set in the Euclidean plane

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I got stuck on the following problem. Prove that there exists a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that every line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ goes exactly through **two** points in $A$. I know that I should apply the axiom of choice in some clever way but I can't think of it. Can someone help me?

Comment: It might help to know what form of the Axiom of Choice you're supposed to use.

Comment: @GitGud: Does it matter? You could probably prove this with the assumption that every vector space has a Hamel basis, by somehow considering the lines as a vector space over some field and using the basis to generate such set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It might matter to the OP. He could have trouble translating your answer into the AC's form he's more used to. PS: I knew you were gonna answer this question.

Comment: @GitGud: If the question is tagged [axiom-of-choice] it's rare that I won't give an answer. Combine the fact that AC is my research focus, and that I am almost all the time on the site...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Plus you're a genius, to be honest.

Comment: @GitGud: I don't know about that. I can just admit that I have gained a sufficient amount of experience over the last two years that I've been interested in this topic. There's plenty I don't know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $A$ to be the set of all lines, note that its cardinality is $2^{\aleph_0}$, so we can enumerate it $A=\{L_\alpha\mid\alpha<2^{\aleph_0}\}$.

We define by transfinite induction sets $C_\alpha\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ such that for every $\beta,\alpha<2^{\aleph_0}$: $|C_\alpha|<2^{\aleph_0}$ and $|C_\alpha\cap L_\beta|\leq 2$.

If $C_\beta$ was defined for all $\beta<\alpha$, let $\gamma$ be the least ordinal such that $L_\gamma\cap\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} C_\beta$ has at most one point. Since two distinct lines meet at at most one point the set $\bigcup_{\delta<\gamma}(L_\delta\cap L_\gamma)$ has size $<2^{\aleph_0}$ and therefore the set $L_\gamma\setminus\Big(\bigcup_{\beta<\gamma} L_\beta\, \cup\, \bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} C_\beta\Big)$ is non-empty, and we can choose $x_\alpha$ from it.

Let $C_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} C_\alpha\cup\{x_\alpha\}$. And let $C=\bigcup_{\alpha<2^{\aleph_0}} C_\alpha$ be our set. As this is a homework assignment, I leave it to you to verify this part (and to formalize the above argument better).

---

Equally, and perhaps more easily, you could do this with Zorn's lemma, by defining the partially order set of all those subsets of the plane which meet every line in *at most* two points, and order it by inclusion.

Show that every chain has an upper bound (i.e. the increasing union of such sets is itself a set with this property), and conclude that the maximal element is the one you are after.

Comment: Such sets are called "2-point sets" in the plane. It's still an open problem (people at my old university have worked on it quite a bit!) whether a Borel 2-point set exists..

Comment: See http://www.cs.elte.hu/~vidnyanz/el1.pdf for an overview of the problem. It's quite intriguing

Comment: @Henno: Pretty cool.

Comment: This is an example of what Gowers calls "Just-do-it proofs": http://gowers.wordpress.com/2008/08/16/just-do-it-proofs/

Comment: @AsafKaragila About your second idea to solve the problem (use of Zorn'n Lemma): Every circle is a maximal element of your partially ordered set (i.e., as you suggested: the family of those subsets of the plane which meet every line in at most two points). So if this approach gonna work then we can drop the zorn part and start with a given circle.

Comment: @alex: You're right about circles being maximal. But a circle is certainly not a set which meets *every* line in exactly two points (e.g. tangent lines are met only in one point, and plenty of lines don't even intersect a circle). Moreover, by its very maximality it means that you can't quite start with a circle either. You need to be able and add more points to the set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  I just wanted to make the point that the second approach (as you have sketched) does not work since if "the maximal element is the one you are after" (as you have said) then a circle should also work !

Comment: @alex: Yeah, I get that. I'll see if I can think of an easy way to fix this.